# What does "Information" and Virtual Particles mean?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, information, virtual-particles

I've read that attraction and repulsion between particles is caused by the exchange of [virtual photons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle), and that virtual photons carry [information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_information).

I don't understand how a virtual photon actually causes any attraction or repulsion, and how does it carry information anyway if it's "virtual"?

Aren't photons an excitation of the electromagnetic field?

Comment: See, for example:  http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Quantum/virtual_particles.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual particles, whether photons or electrons or... are, in the context of QFT, particles that are [off-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_shell_and_off_shell), i.e., their associated energy and momentum are not related by the relativistic [energy-momentum relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation).

Please read [this](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Quantum/virtual_particles.html) to get an idea of how virtual particle exchange can create attractive or repulsive forces.

Photons are *quanta* of the modes of the *quantized* electromagnetic field.  This isn't easy to explain without some background in the quantum harmonic oscillator and, even then...

However, imagine that a guitar string can vibrate with only discrete amplitudes and these amplitudes have an energy that is a multiple of a fundamental energy.

Then, if the guitar string were vibrating with the 1 unit of this fundamental energy, we would say that 1 "photon" of guitar string vibration were present.  If the string were vibrating with *n* units of this fundamental energy, we would say that *n* "photons" were present.